# Solving Coupled Differential Equations with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Does someone know if it is possible to solve this type of coupled differential equations with NDSolve?:

[image] The dot indicates a $\Lambda$-derivation. I am just asking if it is possible to do this in principle, before i waste 6 hours trying. Which I will attempt to do if noone answers.

**EDIT**

Ok, so i tried to solve a somewhat similar but simpler equation system:

$\partial_{x1}y_1(x1,x2)=y_1(x1,x2)$, $\partial_{x1}y_2(x1)=y_1(x1,x1)$

with initial conditions: $y1(0,x2)=\delta_{0,x2} \ , y2(0)=0$

My code is

`s = NDSolve[{D[y1[x1, x2], x1] == y1[x1, x2], 
   D[y2[x1], x1] == y1[x1, x1], y2[0] == 0, 
   y1[0, x2] == KroneckerDelta[x2, 0]}, y2, {x1, 0, 30}]`

The Problem i encounter here is that NDSolve gives me an error that initial conditions need to be numbers.

**EDIT**

If I add {x2,0,30} I get the error "the arguments should be ordered consistently", this is the error I want to avoid..

Comment: This system of equations can be solved numerically. I do not understand the notation $[k_1<->k_3,k_2<->k_4]$. What does this mean?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I guess it means the previous term shall be repeated with the indicated perturbations of indices applied.

Comment: @AGP As Alex already said: It should be possible to solve the system numerically. A first step would be the translation of these expression into Mathematica. And it is also not clear to me what $k_1,\cdots$ are supposed to be let alone $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $\beta$.

Comment: Ok so for some reason I need reputation to comment? So this answer is actually a comment: Henrik is right about the permutations. The $\gamma$'s are so called vertexfunctions, $\beta=1/k_bT$ and the k's are frequencies, this is a physics problem, specifically a Renormalization Group problem. And i just found the edit option. yey.

Comment: @AGP I have converted your non-answer into a real comment. I'm not sure why you have two different accounts with the same name. Try to get them merged because *you* can always comment under your own questions. To comment everywhere however, you need 50 reputation points.

Comment: @A G P It is necessary to use the parametric dependence of the function y1 on x2 and the corresponding solver ParametricNDSolveValue